# Cropping map in ArcGIS layout

Tags: arcgis-pro

This may seem like a simple question, but I cannot seem to just get the part I want from the map layer in the layout tab in ArcGIS pro.

This is a view of what it looks like,

[image]

I just want the part where the kernel density layer is plus a part of that basemap.

I try to resize it but then it does not achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clip/crop the the map to a layer this is a property of the Map DataFrame.

1. Right click on your Data Frame in TOC and select properties
2. Select **Clip Layers**
3. Set drop down to *Clip to a custom extent* and complete the rest of the dialog.

[image: Screen shot]

You can use vector or raster layers to clip.As always more information is found in the [Help File](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/properties/clip-layers-in-a-map.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In the layout select the Map Frame, then in the Edit group click the Reshape drop-down menu and choose a draw tool - Rectangle is easy for a standard map. Then just draw the new rectangle over the area of your map you want it to crop to!